# Find all complex roots of $T^4-{1/2}T^2-\sqrt{15}T+{69/16}$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, galois-theory, roots, irreducible-polynomials

I want to find all complex roots of $T^4-{1/2}T^2-\sqrt{15}T+{69/16}$.

---

The only way I can think to do it is to find 1 complex root, $\alpha$, by inspection, so we can rearrange the polynomial to be $(T-\alpha)(T^3+pT^2+qt+r) $then show the cubic equation is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion. But I do not think this is going to work, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: for what stands $T$ her?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $T$ is the indeterminate of the polynomial in $\Bbb{C}[T]$.

Comment: A variable. $T^4-{1/2}T^2-\sqrt{15}T+{69/16}=0$ I am trying to find all complex numbers, that can replace T,  which satisfy this equation (i.e. are roots). Does that make sense?

Comment: @thinker Yes it makes sense. The only thing I cannot understand is where does this strange polynomial come from.

Comment: It is a question from a course I am taking on Galois Theory @Crostul

Comment: this equation has only complex roots

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, the question is "find the complex roots"

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-x%5E2%2F2-sqrt%2815%29x%2B69%2F16) gives us the exact roots.

Comment: By the way, you can't expect to use Eisenstein criterion. It only works for rational polynomials, not complex ones.

Comment: Actually, Eisenstein is good for far more constant rings than just $\Bbb Z$. Still doesn’t help you here, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better, I think, to try with $x^4-2x^2-8\sqrt{15}\space x+69$ where $x=2T$.

By some tedious calculation of undetermined coefficients we have

$x^4-2x^2-8\sqrt{15}\space x+69=[x^2-2\sqrt {5}\space  x +(9-2\sqrt 3)]\cdot[x^2+2\sqrt {5}\space  x +(9+2\sqrt 3)]$

Hence $x_{1,2}=\sqrt 5\pm\sqrt{4-2\sqrt 3}\space i$ and $x_{3,4}=-\sqrt 5\pm \sqrt{4+2\sqrt 3}\space i$

Thus $$\color{red}{\begin{cases}2T_{1,2}=\sqrt 5\pm\sqrt{4-2\sqrt 3}\space i\\ 2T_{3,4}=-\sqrt 5\pm \sqrt{4+2\sqrt 3}\space i\end{cases}}$$
*The verification can be made by*

$[(x-\sqrt 5)^2+(\sqrt 3-1)^2][ x+\sqrt 5)^2+(\sqrt 3+1)^2]=x^4-2x^2-8\sqrt{15}\space x+69$.

Comment: great, thanks. Did you use the quadratic formula to get $x_{1,2}$ and $x_{3,4}$?

Comment: also, please may you briefly outline what the 'undetermined coefficients' method is? Is this where you put unknown constants such as a, b, c in front of the powers of x, and then find restrictions that allow them to be determined? cheers @Piquito

Comment: That's right. The restrictions you mention are just the equality of coefficients but when the involved numbers are not integer it is something more complicated and you have to pay attention more than usual.

Comment: Yes, each factor being quadratic it is the quadratic formula you apply inmediately (quadratic factors are better than the linear one you wanted to find and this because each complex must be acompanied by its conjugated).